# How to configure Multiple Tablerates module

Tags: magento

I'm trying to configure `Multiple Tablerates` module. Here is how it should be done:

If `weight < 350` than `Shipping costs = 20`
If `weight > 350 AND weight < 500` than `Shipping costs = 25`
If `weight > 500 AND weight < 1000` than `Shipping costs = 45`

Here is my CSV content:

```
USA,*,*,350.0000,20.0000,pp-ppp,Priority Mail International,Poczta Polska,value
USA,*,*,500.0000,25.0000,pp-ppp,Priority Mail International,Poczta Polska,value
USA,*,*,1000.0000,45.0000,pp-ppp,Priority Mail International,Poczta Polska,value
```

But it don't wan't to work. It's hard to explain what's the exact problem cause it's completely unpredictable (but for example, shipping costs for items which weights are 0.3 and 0.7 are `45`). Can anyone tell me if my CSV file looks correct ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what do you mean "Multiple Tablerates", nevertheless for standard "Table Rate" **there is missing the header line** in CSV. Moreover last three columns are unnecessary.

Try import something like this:

```
Country,Region,Zip,Weight,Price
USA,*,*,350.0000,20.0000
USA,*,*,500.0000,25.0000
USA,*,*,1000.0000,45.0000
```

You can also check the imported data in table "shipping_tablerate in your DB.

Comment: looks like it was something wrong with the Multiple Tablerates module i was using. Now i'm using a normal Table Rates module and it works fine. Thank's for your help :)